# UnityScript to C# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a code in UnityScript and I want to convert it in C# but this is what happened.

```
Assets/My Scripts/projectileShot2.cs(23,52): error CS0019: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' and 'float'

Assets/My Scripts/projectileShot2.cs(22,36): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Assets/My Scripts/projectileShot2.cs(21,35): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

this was the code for UnityScript

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {    
}

var canonPrefab : Transform;
var speed = 0f ;
var angle = 0f;
var time = 5.0f;

function Update(){
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    var canon: Transform =  Instantiate (canonPrefab, transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    var shootDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * Vector3.right;
    canon.rigidbody.velocity = shootDir * speed;
    Destroy(canon, 5.0f);
}

if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q)){
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, 0, 30.0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        angle += 1;
    }

if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)){
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, 0, -30.0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        angle -= 1;
    }
}
```

and this was the C# code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class projectileShot2 : MonoBehaviour {


    public Transform cannonPrefab;
    public float speed = 0f;
    public float angle = 0f;
    public float time = 0f;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
            Transform canon = Instantiate(cannonPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Quaternion shootDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * Vector3.right;
            canon.rigidbody.velocity = shootDir * speed;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q)){
            transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, 0, 30.0f) * Time.deltaTime);
            angle += 1;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)){
            transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, 0, -30.0f) * Time.deltaTime);
            angle -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Im still a newbie with this scripting and still not familiar with the data types. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this scenario multiple times at work, and have made heavy use of [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). You let it compile to an assembly (the Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-*.dll files), then use ILSpy to read and decompile the result to the language of your choice (like C#).

It has a few bugs and quirks that you still have to overcome, but since it does all the heavy lifting for you, there's minimal amount that you have to hand-tweak to fit with the rest of your code.

**EDIT 1:**

On line **23**, you have:

```
canon.rigidbody.velocity = shootDir * speed;
```

`shootDir` is a Quaternian, and while you can multiply by a `Vector3` (more explanation about that [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/372371/multiply-quaternion-by-vector3-how-is-done.html)), you cannot multiply by `speed`. Try `speed * Vector3.forward` or some other direction.

**EDIT 2:**

On line **21**, you need to change it from `Instantiate(cannonPrefab,` to `Instantiate(cannonPrefab.gameObject,`

**EDIT 3:**

I'm not entirely sure about line **22**, but I wonder what would happen if you wrapped everything right of the `=` sign in parentheses, and whether that would get rid of that error/warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think i've got the answer, What I did is, with javascript, I use typeof to identify the datatype of shootDir and print it. After that I found out that it was a Vector3. Then I change the datatype from Quaternion to Vector3 in my C# script and it already worked! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with the correct data types, you can always check the [Unity Scripting Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html). I linked the corresponding sites in my answers below. Let's check every error and why the compiler is complaining.

**Line 21:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

You are trying to assign an `Object` to a `Transform` variable and while the compiler cannot handle it by itself, it is already giving you a hint what might be the correct solution.

[`Instantiate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) always returns an `Object` as result, so you have to cast it back to the type of your prefab using the keyword `as`. In this case you're cloning a `Transform` object, so the correct code would be:

```
Transform canon = Instantiate(cannonPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
```

---

**Line 22:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'
```

Now you're trying to assign a `Vector3` to a `Quaternion` variable and again there is no way for the compiler to handle this.

If you [multiply](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) a `Quaternion` with a `Vector3` you get a `Vector3` as a result, so you simply have to change `shootDir` to a `Vector3`

```
Vector3 shootDir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * Vector3.right;
```

---

**Line 23:**

```
Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' and 'float'
```

You cannot multiply a `Quaternion` with a `float` but because `shootDir` is now a `Vector3` the multiplication with a `float` is no longer a problem.